# Why doesn't this Vim mapping for bubbling text work as expected?

Tags: vim

So I followed the instructions here: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/bubbling-text/

The idea is that I enter visual mode and select a few lines of text.  Then I hit CTRL-k or CTRL-j to move the selected text up or down in my file.  The mappings in my .vimrc file are as follows:

```
nmap <C-k> ddkP
nmap <C-j> ddp
vmap <C-k> xkP`[V`]
vmap <C-j> xp`[V`]
```

The first two mappings are for normal mode (`nmap`) and they work as expected.  For going down, the `dd` command deletes a line and the `p` command moves the cursor down and inserts the line.  For going up the `dd` command deletes the line, the `k` command moves the cursor up a line, and then the `P` command inserts the line above.

In visual mode, however, it doesn't work. Take the case of moving several lines of selected text down.  Once the text is selected the `x` command deletes it.  But the `p` command inserts the text exactly where the cursor is.  So if I have a file with the following contents:

```
one
two
three
```

and the cursor is on the "o" of one. I hit `vj$` to select the first two lines.  Then I hit `x` to delete them.  Then I hit `p` to insert them below.  The result looks like this:

```
tone
two
hree
```

Right before I hit `p`, there is a single line in the file and the cursor is sitting on the "t" in "three".  So the behavior makes sense to me.  What I don't understand is why the expert VimCast tutorial is expecting me to see different behavior.  Also, I would like to get the behavior I would like.

Comment: Drew suggested in that Vimcast episode to use Unimpaired.vim. I suggest you give it a try. It is a very helpful plugin. https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those mappings work perfectly.

If we take the `<C-j>` visual mode mapping:

- `x` deletes the visual selection which puts the cursor on the line directly below the the delete lines.
- `p` puts the deleted lines *under* the current line, that's the intended effect.
- `` `[ `` moves the cursor to the first character of the changed text, here it's the first character of the lines that you moved.
- `V` starts visual-line selection
- `` `] `` extends the selection toward the last character of the moved text, ready for further moving.

From your description, I think that your problem is twofold:

1. You seem to be using the sequence of commands on the right hand of the mapping instead of the mapping itself.
2. You are using `v` (visual mode, lowercase `v`, character-wise) instead of `V` (visual-line mode, capital `v`, line-wise). The purpose of these mappings is to "bubble" lines, not words so, if you *really* want the desired effect, you must use the right visual mode.

The correct sequence of commands is:

```
Vj<C-j>
```

or, if you insist on not using Drew Neil's mapping:

```
Vjxp`[V`]
```

Comment: Thanks -- it works if I enter visual mode using capital `V`.  I was using lower case `v` before.  The reason I was using the sequence of commands on the right of the mapping is because the mapping wasn't working for me and I was trying to debug it by stepping through the sequence slowly.  But capital `V` solved it.